# Who filled up the potion between the time Dumbledore drank it and Voldemort went to see it?

Tags: harry-potter

**Warning** Contains spoilers.

At the end of *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Dumbledore drinks the potion. Harry even says that the goblet scrapes the bottom of the basin.

> Dumbledore drank like a child dying of thirst, but when he had finished, he yelled again as though his insides were on fire. "No more, please, no more ..."
>
> Harry scooped up a tenth goblet of potion and felt the crystal scrape the bottom of the basin. "We’re nearly there, Professor. Drink this, drink it. ..."
>
> He supported Dumbledore’s shoulders and again, Dumbledore drained the glass; then Harry was on his feet once more, refilling the goblet as Dumbledore began to scream in more anguish than ever, "I want to die! I want to die! Make it stop, make it stop, I want to die!"
>
> "Drink this, Professor. Drink this. ..."
>
> Dumbledore drank, and no sooner had he finished than he yelled, "KILL ME!"
>
> "This — this one will!” gasped Harry. “Just drink this ... It’ll be over ...all over!"
>
> Dumbledore gulped at the goblet, drained every last drop, and then, with a great, rattling gasp, rolled over onto his face.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

Neither Harry nor Dumbledore filled the basin with the potion when leaving. Yet, in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Voldemort looks into a basin filled with potion once more.

> "Potter,” said Professor McGonagall, turning to face him again with superb indifference to the Carrows’ predicament. "if He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named does indeed know that you are here— "
>
> As she said it, awrath that was like physical pain blazed through Harry, setting his scar on fire, and for a second he looked down upon a basin whose potion had turned clear, and saw that no golden locket lay safe beneath the surface—
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

**Edit:** Also, Voldemort had to refill the basin with the potion the time he went to the underground lake with Kreacher.

> "Kreacher drank, and as he drank he saw terrible things . . . Kreacher’s insides burned . . . Kreacher cried for Master Regulus to save him, he cried for his Mistress Black, but the Dark Lord only laughed . . . He made Kreacher drink all the potion . . . He dropped a locket into the empty basin . . . He filled it with more potion."
>
> "And then the Dark Lord sailed away, leaving Kreacher on the island . . . "
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

### During the time between when Dumbledore drank the potion and Voldemort when to see if the locket was still there, who filled the basin with the potion?

*Note*: My question is not a duplicate [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236781/who-drank-the-green-potion-when-voldemort-went-checking-for-the-locket). I am asking for who, not how.

Comment: A wizard did it.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Yes, it was magic too. ;D

Comment: Why would Voldemort create an obstacle that would block only the first intruder to reach it?  Most likely it was set to refill itself.

Comment: @Mary I recall Voldemort had to refill it during the time Kreacher drank it. I will edit the quote in.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/43545/21267

Comment: @Möoz Is there a canon something approved by JK Rowling that can be used to answer instead of educated guesswork though?

Comment: @Silvermidnight Not so far as I recall. The closest are the questions I posted as related.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157460/21267

Comment: Also, I suspect the who and how are closely related enough in this case to have the same answer.

Comment: @Möoz So technically 3 questions about the same thing with no 100% answer.

Comment: @Silvermidnight All definitely very closely related for sure.